# Network management switch and data transfer switch in an HPC cluster

Tags: networking, switch, hpc

Shown in the image is a validated design from Dell for an HPC with AI workload. We are using this reference in our HPC design. The image is taken from this white paper by Dell on page 12: [HPC Validated Design for AI and Data Analytics](https://www.delltechnologies.com/asset/sk-sk/products/converged-infrastructure/technical-support/h18161-hpc-ra-for-ai-da-ra.pdf)

[image: network schematic from PDF]

As far as I understand, the S3048-ON switch manages the communication among nodes, and the S5232F-ON manages the data flow/transfer between nodes. In the image, both the switches are connected to the management, compute, and storage nodes. I would like to know how these are actually implemented. Any help would be valuable. Thank you

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Brand of switches in an HPC cluster](https://superuser.com/questions/1763731/brand-of-switches-in-an-hpc-cluster)

Comment: Please don't post the same question again. Instead, edit your original question.

Comment: The goal of the previous question was to compare different brands of switches. In this question, I wanted to understand how the configuration of network switches are implemented (since the image specifies two network switch - one for management, and one for the data transfer). Sorry I did not edit it as I think that this question is different from the previous one.